# how to make the element selection to return null instead of throw error in applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am debugging a legacy desktop automation tool which use AppleScript for UI control on MacOS. One of the script keeps failing with `error "System Events got an error: Can’t get static text \"2\" of window \"UISoup – mac_utils.py\" of application process \"pycharm\"." number -1728 from static text "2" of window "UISoup – mac_utils.py" of application process "pycharm"`, and here is the script

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "PyCharm"
    set visible to true
    set uiElement to static text "2" of window "UISoup – mac_utils.py" of application process "pycharm" of application "System Events"
    set layer to 1
    if uiElement = null then
        set layer to 0
        set collectedElements to {UI elements of front window, layer}
    else
        set layer to layer + 1
        set collectedElements to {null, layer}
        if name of attributes of uiElement contains "AXChildren" then
            set collectedElements to {value of attribute "AXChildren" of uiElement, layer}
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

It seems like this line `set uiElement to static text "2" of window "UISoup – mac_utils.py" of application process "pycharm" of application "System Events"` should set the `uiElement` to `null` if the element is not found. But in fact it will throw error instead.  How to let it return `null` instead of throw error to make it works? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a [try statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128973) to catch the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AppleScript equivalent of **null** is **missing value**. When GUI scripting, the process should be **frontmost**. You can check existing of UI elements using command **exists** (you can use try block as well).

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "PyCharm"
    set frontmost to true
    -- set visible to true
    set uiElementExists to exists static text "2" of window "UISoup – mac_utils.py"
    set layer to 1
    if not uiElementExists then
        set layer to 0
        set collectedElements to {UI elements of front window, layer}
    else
        set layer to layer + 1
        set collectedElements to {missing value, layer}
        set uiElement to static text "2" of window "UISoup – mac_utils.py"
        if name of attributes of uiElement contains "AXChildren" then
            set collectedElements to {value of attribute "AXChildren" of uiElement, layer}
        end if
    end if
end tell
```